# Is $\mathbb{Q}^2$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^2\setminus \{0\}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ are not homeomorphic. (For examle $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)=\{e\}$, but $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\})=\mathbb{Z}$).

But what can be said about $\mathbb{Q}^2$ and $\mathbb{Q}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$? Is there a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The rational numbers are the unique (up to isomorphism) metric space which is both countable and have no isolated points.

$\Bbb Q^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is countable and without isolated points. Therefore the answer is yes. There is a homeomorphism.

Comment: http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf here are the proofs of the Sierpiński theorem you refer to.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood something, the same argument proves that there's a homeomorphism between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^2$.  That seemed unlikely, but I did a Google search immediately produced http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26001/are-the-rationals-homeomorphic-to-any-power-of-the-rationals/26009#26009 .  Thanks!

Comment: @MJD: You're welcome, I guess. :-)