# Showing $\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of rationals, as relative topology to $\mathbb{R}$.

How to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^2$?

More general, if $T$ is a countable dense space(no isolated poiont) with every singleton closed, how to show that $T^2$ is homeomophic to $T$.

Comment: If $T$ is a countable dense space with every singleton closed then $T$ is homeomorphic to exactly one of the following: $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$; $(0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$; $(0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Also, see the links in the comments to [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323900/is-mathbbq2-homeomorphic-to-mathbbq2-setminus-0/323903#323903).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Aren't these three spaces homeomorphic to each other since they are metric countable with no isolated point ?

Comment: @user10676: Hm, yeah, I suppose that I had in mind order isomorphism (or order-reversing).

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila . I found that the MO answer  thru your link is very nice, especially its simplicity is surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the unique (up to homeomorphism) countable metric space without isolated points. Three proofs can be found [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf).