# Topological equivalence between $\mathbb Q^2$ and $S\subset\mathbb R$

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm wondering if the metric spaces $S:=\{x+y\sqrt{2}:x,y\in\mathbb Q\}$ and $\mathbb Q^2$, with metrics induced by $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ respectively, are topologically equivalent. I know that the function $f:\mathbb Q^2\to S$ defined by $f(x,y):=x+y\sqrt{2}$ is bijective, but how can I show that $f$ is continuous / not continuous?

Comment: Are you okay with just saying it’s linear therefore continuous?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355779/showing-mathbbq-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbbq2#1642728 and the surprising result in the answer.

Comment: Maybe first show that $f(x,y):=x+y\sqrt{2}$ is continuous from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.  Then conclude it is continuous with the induced metrics.  But that does not work for the inverse map, which is not continuous.  The two spaces are homeomorphic, but not by that map.

Comment: Can you name a map that works? @CEdgar

Comment: I think @GEdgar was who you meant to tag.

Comment: Can I **name** a map?  No.  But I can cite: "Sierpinski proved that every countable metric space without isolated points is homeomorphic to the rationals"

Comment: Ok, thanks! @GEdgar

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of [Showing $\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355779/showing-mathbbq-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbbq2)